# Angular 2's Input and Output naming convention, to follow styleguide?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-styleguide

Input and outputs, how to work with them to follow the naming convention of the Angular 2's styleguide?

Before I knew any better I used to have my directive defined like this:

```
...
inputs: [
  'onOutside'
]
... 

export class ClickOutsideDirective {
  @Output() onOutside: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

But then I read the styleguide and it said that you should not prefix your outputs with `on` since Angular 2 supports the `on-` syntax in the templates.

So I'm trying to change it to something like:

```
@Input() outsideClick: any;
@Output() outsideClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

However, I'm finding it difficult to separate the `@Input` name from the `Output` name if you aren't allowed to use the `on` prefix.

Before you could name both the `@Input` and `@Output` the same thing but if declaring both within the exported class then this no longer works since an error will be thrown.

If I name the `@Input` to `outside` and the `@Output` to `outsideClick`, it doesn't really make sense since both of them are the same thing. `outside` is the function I want to execute when calling `outsideClick`.

Also, `outsideClick` won't know what to execute if `outside` isn't name the same thing anymore, or am I missing something?

How should I approach naming the `@Input` and `@Output` variables here so that it still works and makes as much sense as it did in the first example?

**EDIT:**

Usage example:

```
<div clickOutside [exceptions]="['.toggler']" (outside)="doSomethingOnOutsideClick()"></div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Definitely don't use `on`. In JavaScript events also don't start with `on`. Only the event handlers do. There is no `onClick` event in JS. The event name is `click` and if you assign a function to `onClick` this function will be called when the `click` event was received.

If you have inputs and outputs that belong together name them

```
@Input() name:any; 
@Output() nameChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();;
```

This allows the short hand for Angular2 "two-way binding"

```
[(name)]="someProp"
```

If you use `@Input()` and `@Output()` (preferred way) then you don't need `inputs: []` and `outputs: []`. These are two ways to do the same thing and if you use both one is redundant.

To match the browser naming scheme what you could do is

```
(nameChange)="onNameChange($event)"
```

to have an event handler `onNameChange` to be called when the `nameChange` event is received.

When the event is not part of an input/output pair you can or should omit the `Change`

```
(loggedIn)="onLoggedIn($event)
```

Comment: But that doesn't make sense if `outsideClick` is a function that should be called, it doesn't change..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. What do you mean with `if outsideClick` is a function. Can you add a code example to your question?

Comment: I updated my answer (before I saw your edit). What exactly do you think doesn't make sense? What is the semantic of the `(outside)` event?

Comment: It might be me who is just confused.. If `outside` is a function, then I would emit it via `outsideChange.emit()` right? So technically I could just do `@Output('outsideChange') outsideClick ......`?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "if `outside` is a function". Your question doesn't contain a function with that name. Can you add to your question how such code would look like?

Comment: I have, `outside` is just the input where I say what function that should be called when you actually click outside. Like `(outside)="closeModal()"` or something like that. Get it?

Comment: Actually no. With `(outside)` `outside` has to be an `EventEmitter` not a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125222/discussion-between-chrillewoodz-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the OP made multiple questions, but with same context (hence below has multiple sections).

### Usage and/or definition

If you want to support Angular-2 and later-version's "two-way binding",
then pair input with a `Change` suffixed output, like:

```
@Input() password: string;
@Output() passwordChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
```

This allows short-hand(s) like:

```html
<app-my-component
    [(password)]="myPasswordProp"
    >
</app-my-component>
```

> Above I pass default-value to component as input,
> and take user's changes as output,
> basically syncing `myPasswordProp` with `MyComponent`'s internal state.

### Naming convention

In `Angular-2`+ use "`on`" prefix only for event-handlers, never event-emitters.

> **Note** that "`on`" prefix is not allowed for events (and even causes compile error, at least in newer Angular versions).

Even in `JavaScript`, there is no `onClick` named event, the event name is `click`.
The only difference is that JS uses `onClick` as name of attribute where we pass event-handler, while Angular forbids that prefix.

Angular at least allows using `on` for event-handlers, like:

```
(passwordChange)="onPasswordChange($event)"
```

> Where the `onPasswordChange` named event-handler is called when the `passwordChange` event is triggered.

But if the event is **not** part of an input/output pair, we should omit the `Change` suffix while defining the output, and use it like:

```
(loggedIn)="onLoggedIn($event)"
```

**Or further more**, to have a prefix like Browser's naming-scheme,
and/or to separate events from other things,
our company did use "`by`" prefix instead, like:

```
(byLogin)="onLogin($event)"

(bySave)="onSave($event)"
```

> Which is far more readable, because it **can** be part of human-sentences, like:
>
> - "Our App's handler is pending **on login** to happen, which is triggered **by login** event(s) of the library."
>
> Or the other way around:
>
> - "The library does **by login** event(s) trigger our App's handler, which is pending **on login** to happen."
>
> Readability is one of the reasons why both "on" and "by" prefixes can be used the way they are.

### Class-annotation vs Property-annotation

Just because OP mentioned it:

- Using `@Input()` and/or `@Output()` annotation with member-variable(s) is the preferred way.
- If you use above, then you don't need to pass `inputs: []` and/or `outputs: []` to class' annotation.
- Basically, these are two approaches to achive the same thing, and if you use one, the other one is redundant.

Comment: I like the "by" thing, might start using it.